# javascript add variable onto end of link

Tags: javascript, variables, hyperlink, href

I'm trying to add a variable i created on to the end of one of my links but not sure how to do it?

```
<a href="../../availability/default.aspx?propid=' + myvariable + '">Link</a>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Jamie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this will create a closure which will store your original `HREF` property:

```
function init() {
    var link = document.getElementById("link");
    var hrefOrig = link.href;
    var dd = document.getElementById("DropDown");
    dd.onchange = function(){ link.href = hrefOrig + dd.value; }
}

window.addEventListener("load", init, false); // for Firefox; for IE, try window.attachEvent
```

Answer (score 3):

Add an ID:

```
<a id="link" href="../../availability/default.aspx?propid=">Link</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.links["link"].href += myvariable;
```

jQuery:

```
$('#link').attr('href', $('#link').attr('href') + myvariable);
```

Comment: I've got a bit of an issue in that i am adding the variable onchange of a drop down list and it keeps adding it on to href everytime change the drop down?

Comment: if you don`t require a valid html you can add attribute "basic_href" to the A-tag and change the code of Adam like:
$('#link').attr('href', $('#link').attr('basic_href') + myvariable);

Answer (score 0):

The solution is only to adapt the code that Adam post above so:

HTML

```
<a id="link" href="">Link</a>

<select onchange="addVariable(this.value)">...
```

Javascript

```
function addVariable(myvariable){

document.links["link"].href = "../../availability/default.aspx?propid=" + myvariable;

}
```